# Filter numerical html table values, by comparison and not string search

Tags: javascript, html

I want to filter the numerical values of a HTML column using a direct comparison of numbers from user-input values.

This shows no output.

```js
function myFunction2() {
 var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
 input = document.getElementById('myInput2').value
 var pctstr="0"
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for (i = 0; i <= tr.length; i++) {
   td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
   if (td) {
     txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
     if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
       tr[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
       tr[i].style.display = "none";
     }
   }       
 }
}
```

Comment: You will have to add a [mcve] of the markup with the expected result for a given input if you want an answer that works with your setup.

Comment: Arrays are zero-based which you seem to already know (`i = 0`). This also results in the fact that the last element in an array is at index `array.length - 1` and not at `array.length` (`i <= tr.length`).